# Window Flashing and Stucco - Does a new vinyl window need a drip cap?

Tags: windows, stucco, flashing

**Context:** Installing new Milgard vinyl windows and planning to install a drip cap. The windows have a 1" setback flange for stucco in addition of the flange to be placed against the framing. I am not clear on the shape of drip cap to use. See sketch.

**Questions:**

- Does a new vinyl window with two flanges need a drip cap?

A drip cap would block the stucco to be placed behind the stucco flange.

- Or does the drip cap have to follow the shape of the channel?

[image: Top of window flanges]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.wixsys.com/images/StuccoInst.pdf What does the window install manual say?

Comment: Thank you @P2000. Your document is awesome, but does not address what I am looking for exactly. The manufacturer refers to the "Standard Practice for Windows with a Mounting Flange in Wood Frame Construction Using Exterior Barriers Methods" https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jr4YCRjbcnToApXv-oV4wJGK8-xhbdwN/view. Which is also helpful, but does not refer to a drip cap. I am under the impression that this type of Vinyl window do not need a drip cap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Flashing - Stucco 1" setback - Do I need a drip cap?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/264006/windows-flashing-stucco-1-setback-do-i-need-a-drip-cap)

Comment: Voting to close as this is a duplicate of your other question from a day or two ago. This annotated drawing is _very_ helpful, but should have been edited into the other question instead of being posted in a duplicate question.

Comment: @FreeMan I suggest the other duplicate be closed. This one has better illustration and an answer. (I can't VTC the other one because somehow this one does not show up when attempting to search for the duplicate under "reasons")

Comment: @Max sometimes the drip cap is required by local code. Also, a drip cap not only helps prevent water ingress at the flange, when properly sized for protrusion  it also keeps drips off the panes & seams, which matters for rainy climates. So your local (municipal) building code may require one. Examples I found yesterday show no drip cap (I have no experience with stucco)

Comment: @FreeMan I created a new post and asked the question differently. From experience posting and editing, even after adding additional materials in a post no one answers. While if one creates a new post, then people answer. Is there an incentive in the Stack Exchange to reward the first person who answers vs additional answers?

Comment: @Max when you edit a post it percolates to the top of the home page, and first well rated answers do get rewarded with a medal once the post reaches high numbers of views. What matters most though is that the a single point of discussion is highly beneficial for you and the community.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you!

Comment: @P2000 Actually, I'd have agreed with you, and frankly, I'm surprised the system let me VtC the other one since it didn't have an answer and this one did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most practices in the southeast, a drip cap is not used on that type of window.
However, I have seen where the stucco guys have cut off the channel for stucco to install lath with a metal channel.

Neither method has been noted to be problematic.  I believe it is a choice.

Comment: What happens to any water that makes it's way into the square opening between the stucco flange and the nailing flange? Is there a way for to drain or escape?

Comment: This is exactly why I would like to have a drip cap. That area seems to be water tight, that said the documentation does not say so. Also, If the area is perfectly horizontal I dont see how the water would drain and escape.

Comment: @SteveSh yeah I don't understand either, unless there are weeping holes. That's a cavity if drip capped. Perhaps OP can include a link to the window.

Comment: Links to window details: https://www.milgard.com/sites/default/files/technical-resources/files/trinsic_2530_fc_1in_stucco_0.pdf